# Page slug repeats endlessly when redirecting Wordpress page on localhost using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've read a lot of similar questions but none of them seem to work for me or be applicable.

I have a Wordpress site that I'm currently running on localhost for development.

This is the contents of it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

/* The lines added by me */
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /wordpress/about/ /wordpress/about/history/

</IfModule>
# END WordPress

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

The two lines were added by me to redirect my empty About page to its sub-page History, [as recommended here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/).

However, when I then reload the server and go to `localhost/wordpress/about/` in Firefox, I get the following screen:

[image]

Note the tons of extra "history" links appended to the URL. What could be causing this?

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava In the Wordpress root directory under XAMPP: `\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this in `/wordpress/.htaccess`:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /wordpress/about/history/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure to completely clear browser cache or test if from a new browser.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Would never have been able to figure this out, so I'm glad I asked. I changed the order of the rules to move `/about/history` rewrite rule to the very bottom, but it all works. One minor thing - while `localhost/wordpress/about` redirects perfectly, adding a slash at the end of about results in a 404. Is there any chance of being able to redirect that case too using the above RewriteRules?

Comment: No, `localhost/wordpress/about` redirects as it should, but `localhost/wordpress/about/` (note the trailing slash) causes a 404. Is there any way to make that redirect in the same way?

Comment: Never mind, it's now working. It seems that two things were getting in my way: 1) I didn't realise the order of the RewriteRules mattered, 2) browser caching, which has never been a problem in all the months I've been coding on this site, so I didn't expect it. Resolving both of those solved the issue. Might just start developing with cache turned off from now on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having trouble adapting this .htaccess file for the same site in production. This is the .htaccess file you recommended, adapting by me for production: https://pastebin.com/99mKVK9M. The moment I replace the default production .htacess file with this one, the entire site starts returning Error 500s. Any ideas what could be wrong with it? Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: no, everything is inside a `public_html` folder, which itself is inside the domain name folder.

Comment: No such luck. Here is what I currently have: https://pastebin.com/TiJzU6Jg.

Comment: oh ok, if `index.php` also exists in `www.mydomain.com` directory then you do need `RewriteBase www.mydomain.com`

Comment: No, `index.php` is also in `public_root`, but changing the RewriteRule from `www.mydomain.com/about/history/` to "/about/history/" doesn't make a difference either. Still returns Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: Can you please open a new question with this 500 problem. Let's take it up there rather than adding lot of comments here.

Comment: No problem, [done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502022/error-500-when-changing-htaccess-file-on-production-server).